# How to move an object in svg path using keyboard

Tags: javascript, svg, html5-canvas

I have an SVG path given below. I need to move that red dot using the keyboard. If a turn coming need to use left or right arrow button based on the turn. How can I achieve this using javascript?

[image]

Comment: Please provide us with what you got so far.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can use left or right arrow to move the red dot the way you intend. In fact I don't understand the logic. Please define right and left tun.

However you can move the dot forwards or backwards by using the right and left arrow.

In my code the starting `value` is 0  and the red dot is at the beginning of the path. The `value` increases or decreases depending on the arrow key you use.

The step is 1/100 of the path's length.

```js
if(e.keyCode == 37){value ++;}
else if(e.keyCode == 39){value --;}
```

If the value is less than 0 or bigger than 100 I reset the value:

```js
if(value > 100){value %= 100;}
if(value < 0){value += 100}
```

I get the position on the path using the `getPointAtLength()` method. I hope this is what you need.

```js
let position = circuit.getPointAtLength(totalLength*value/100);
```

```js
let totalLength = circuit.getTotalLength();


let value = 0;

window.addEventListener("keydown",(e)=>{
  
  if(e.keyCode == 37){value ++;}
  else if(e.keyCode == 39){value --;}
  
  if(value > 100){value %= 100;}
  if(value < 0){value += 100}
  
  let position = circuit.getPointAtLength(totalLength*value/100);
   updateElement({cx:position.x, cy:position.y}, thumb)
  
})



function updateElement(o, element) {
  for (var name in o) {
    if (o.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
      element.setAttributeNS(null, name, o[name]);
    }
  }
  return element;
}
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid #d9d9d9; max-width:100vh}


#circuit{
  stroke:black;
  fill:none;
  stroke-width: 5px;
  stroke-linejoin:round;
  stroke-linecap:round;
  fill-opacity:.85
}

circle{fill:red}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="30 30 300 300">

 <path id="circuit" d="M187.476,214.443c-2.566,11.574-4.541,22.658-7.542,33.456
  c-3.558,12.8-7.14,25.713-12.242,37.938c-10.223,24.495-41.321,29.239-58.824,9.548c-9.592-10.792-11.295-26.9-3.539-40.556
  c11.233-19.778,25.391-37.46,40.447-54.438c1.07-1.207,2.116-2.436,3.893-4.484c-7.212,0.9-13.349,1.988-19.529,2.374
  c-16.283,1.018-32.578,2.21-48.881,2.437c-18.686,0.261-32.846-10.154-37.071-26.055c-6.762-25.449,15.666-48.973,41.418-43.338
  c23.645,5.175,46.447,12.901,68.424,23.051c1.033,0.478,2.083,0.918,3.933,1.731c-0.83-1.947-1.341-3.225-1.911-4.475
  c-9.896-21.701-18.159-43.986-23.192-67.337c-4.587-21.28,8.933-40.56,29.946-43.257c20.134-2.585,38.124,12.991,39.091,34.294
  c1.029,22.682-0.049,45.292-3.58,67.755c-0.17,1.079-0.152,2.188-0.246,3.659c8.05-6.831,15.471-13.737,23.52-19.811
  c11.147-8.412,22.398-16.795,34.27-24.113c18.35-11.312,40.821-4.481,50.028,14.385c9.091,18.628,0.131,40.586-20.065,48.198
  c-11.034,4.158-22.248,7.944-33.594,11.143c-11.321,3.191-22.908,5.438-34.866,8.212c1.189,0.81,2.19,1.504,3.205,2.18
  c18.402,12.261,37.157,24.032,55.101,36.932c14.769,10.616,18.619,29.317,10.675,44.578c-7.537,14.477-25.151,22.136-40.767,17.583
  c-7.583-2.212-14.022-6.469-18.523-12.919c-12.463-17.86-24.638-35.924-36.898-53.925
  C189.24,217.849,188.547,216.357,187.476,214.443z"/>

  
  <circle id="thumb" cx="187.476" cy="214.443" r="5" fill="black" />
  
 
</svg>
```

**Please do not forget to click the iframe before using the keys.**

Answer (score 1):

may be you can use iconic font?

```js
window.focus();
document.addEventListener('keydown', e => {
  let direction = e.keyCode - 38;
  if (Math.abs(direction) !== 1) return;
  let offset = parseFloat(player.getAttribute('startOffset'));
  offset = (offset + direction + 98)%98;
  player.setAttribute('startOffset', offset + '%');
})
```

```html
<svg viewbox=0,0,300,200 width=90vw height=90vh>
    <path id="route" stroke="red" fill="none" d="M75,120L100,0l100,30q110,100,10,150z"/>
    <text><textPath xlink:href="#route" id="player" startOffset="0%"></textPath></text>  
</svg>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function that catches arrow keystrokes. The difference to enxaneta's solution is

- the use of `event.key` instead of `event.keyCode`, which is deprecated. Internet Explorer and Edge < v17 unfortunately use different identifier strings. A complete description of the current state of affairs is [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/key/Key_Values). If you really want to stay with `keyCode`, see [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode#Value_of_keyCode) for compatibility lists.
- if an action is associated with a key, `event.preventDefault()` is set. Otherwise the window might scroll. It is not used globally, as that would block *all* keyboard interactions with the window.

  ```
  document.addEventListener('keydown', function (event) {
      switch (event.key) {
      case 'Left':
      case 'ArrowLeft':
          // game action
          return event.preventDefault();
      case 'Up':
      case 'ArrowUp':
          // game action
          return event.preventDefault();
      case 'Right':
      case 'ArrowRight':
          // game action
          return event.preventDefault();
      case 'Down':
      case 'ArrowDown':
          // game action
          return event.preventDefault();
      }
  });
  ```